# Regular expression in git bash which characters to escape

Tags: regex, git, escaping, git-bash

The regex:

> (feat|fix|hf)/\d*/.*

works great on the following text:

```
Merge pull request #32 in TAS/tashtit from feat/140844/fix-sonar-properties to develop feat/140844/ fixing problems found by sonar Merge pull request #31 in TAS/tashtit from feat/140844/fix-sonar-properties to develop feat/140844/ fix sonar properties and git ignore Merge pull request #30 in TAS/tashtit from feat/141316/jndi-junits to develop Merge pull request #28 in TAS/tashtit from feat/142391/log-event-fix to develop feat/142391/ fix jenkins Merge branch 'develop' into feat/141316/jndi-junits Merge pull request #27 in TAS/tashtit from feat/142391/log-event-fix to develop feat/142391/ Merge branch 'develop' of http://pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7990/scm/tas/tashtit into feat/142391/log-event-fix feat/142391/ fix jenkins Merge branch 'feat/141466/Check-that-refactored-code-works-with-J2EE' into feat/141316/jndi-junits Merge pull request #26 in TAS/tashtit from feat/141466/Check-that-refactored-code-works-with-J2EE to develop feat/141466/ Merge branch 'develop' of ssh://pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit into feat/141466/Check-that-refactored-code-works-with-J2EE feat/141466/ fixing events Merge pull request #25 in TAS/tashtit from feat/141466/Check-that-refactored-code-works-with-J2EE to develop feat/141466/ fixing application port Merge branch 'develop' into feat/141316/jndi-junits Merge branch 'develop' into feat/141316/jndi-junits Merge branch 'develop' into feat/141316/jndi-junits
```

The problem is when writing a command in git bash, I'm getting errors about escaping. Here is the command:

```
git -C /c/workspace/Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build log tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911211325..tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911281247 --grep=(?:feat|fix|hf)\/\d*\/.* --all-match --pretty=%s > /c/workspace/Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build/log.log
```

So, I tried to escape special characters as follows:

```
git -C /c/workspace/Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build log tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911211325..tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911281247 --grep='\(?:feat|fix|hf\)\/\d*\/.*' --all-match --pretty=%s > /c/workspace/Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build/log.log
```

The result was empty, what am I missing?

Comment: Idk if grep takes PCRE—also, single quotes should help with most of the escaping issues.

Comment: tried that, didn't work for me, can you suggest a fix command